# Symmetry of inner product

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, bilinear-form

Peter J. Cameron's "Notes on Linear Algebra" defines

> An inner product on a real vector space $V$ is a function $b: V \times V \to R$ satisfying
>
> b is bilinear (that is, b is linear in the first variable when the second is kept
>   constant and vice versa);
>
> b is positive definite, that is, $b(v,v) \geq 0$ for all $v \in V$, and $b(v,v) = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$.

Using the notation $x \cdot y = b(x,y)$, it then expands (without explanation) $(v+xw) \cdot (v+xw)$ to $x^2 (w \cdot w) + 2x (v \cdot w) + v \cdot v$.

However when I try to verify this, I get to $x^2(w \cdot w) + x(v \cdot w) + x(w \cdot v) + v \cdot v$, which clearly equals the desired expression *if b is symmetric*. But I don't believe we've established anywhere that it is, so I guess I'm either misunderstanding a definition, or I'm missing a trick when performing the expansion.

Comment: Symmetry is generally part of the definition...see, e.g., [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html)  or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)  .

Comment: I believe you are correct and that this is an oversight by the author. I found the book at http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/notes/linalg.pdf and if you are referring to the proof of theorem 6.1 then I agree.

Comment: I'm sure Cameron meant to say that $b$ should be symmetric.